# Get original ID from filtered Listview

Tags: android, listview, search, filter

I have a class in where I can put in a StringArray, and it shows the list with a search box to filter contents. My application is prone that every field has a set ID. However, when I search for a value, the ids change into the filtered list. Is there a way to get the id from the original list, so that even in the filtered list I can have ids like 9, 14 instead of 0, 1, 2....

```
 lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , searchItems));
    ed.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                  int count) {

            textlength = ed.getText().length();
            arr_sort.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < searchItems.length; i++) {
                if (textlength <= searchItems[i].length()) {
                    if (ed.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase((String) searchItems[i].subSequence(0, textlength))) {
                        arr_sort.add(searchItems[i]);
                    }
                }
            }

            lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Rest_Search.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arr_sort));
//                lv1.smoothScrollToPosition(20);
        }
    });
    lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v,
                                int position, long id) {
//                String a = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
//                menuID = (int) id;

            int a = (int) parent.getAdapter().getItemId(position);
//                menuID = (int) parent.getAdapter().getItemId(position);
            Toast.makeText(Rest_Search.this,  ""+a, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize your `adapter`. create a new `Class` extends `BasaAdapter` and Override the `getItemId` method:

```
@Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return items[position].getID();
    }
```

and then in `onItemClick` use item `id`s.

Comment: This worked, all did it gave some problems. Thanks for the quick reply

Answer (score 0):

In your customized adapter use getItemId(pos)

you can obtain pos overriding onClick method of View.OnClickListener()

here an example

```
    private View.OnClickListener mOnAddContactClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        final int position = mListView.getPositionForView(view);
        Log.v(JBOOK,"original id "+getItemId(position));
```